# i am getting fatal error while running the ansible playbook on client machine

Tags: ansible

I have made an Ansible playbook to configure Apache on a fresh machine. When I ran the playbook I got a fatal error for starting the `named` service

```
TASK [command mount-a] *********************************************************
 [WARNING]: Consider using the mount module rather than running 'mount'.  If
you need to use command because mount is insufficient you can add 'warn: false'
to this command task or set 'command_warnings=False' in ansible.cfg to get rid
of this message.

changed: [192.168.43.107]

TASK [run a command] ***********************************************************
 [WARNING]: Consider using the yum module rather than running 'yum'.  If you
need to use command because yum is insufficient you can add 'warn: false' to
this command task or set 'command_warnings=False' in ansible.cfg to get rid of
this message.

changed: [192.168.43.107]

TASK [install package of dns] **************************************************
ok: [192.168.43.107]

TASK [Start service named, if not started] *************************************
fatal: [192.168.43.107]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to start service named: Job for named.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See \"systemctl status named.service\" and \"journalctl -xe\" for details.\n"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.43.107             : ok=8    changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```